# TFVC Merge 2 branches

Tags: tfs, merge, checkout, tfvc

I want to merge 2 branches and I read that if I do the merge,  it will be on my local machine tell I  CheckIn my change. But will all the files that changed when I resolve the conflicts be checked out ? The branches are actually used by other developers so I don't want to block them.

Comment: Exclusive checkouts are an antique practice; you shouldn't be using them. Turn them off or switch to local workspaces if you're using TFS 2012 or later.

Comment: Thanks for responding, So If I work on my local workspaces and I don't CheckIn my merge it will not checkout the files I changed ? By default on my VS I work on my server but I can change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`But will all the files that changed when I resolve the conflicts be checked out ?`

Unless you are working on server workspace and [turn off the multiple check out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/ms242869(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN). Only with this situation, when you check out the branch from sever and do the merge, other developers will not be able to make changes on the branch you are working.

If you are working on **local workspace** or server workspace with multiple check out enable. Others could still work with that branch. They could still get files to local (local workspace) or check out files (server worksapce).

Besides, unless you finally check in your changes to server. They will not able to get the changes you have made.

Hope it's clearly.